# How to query a Dynamo DB having a GSI with only hashKeys using DynamoDBMapper

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, secondary-indexes

I am very new to **Dynamo DB** and may be this is very trivial question, but i went through the documents of Dynamo DB and stack overflow questions but i couldnt find a single link which tells how to query DDB for **GSI** which has only hash key and there are no range key specified for the same.

I get the exception Illegal query expression: No hash key condition is found in the query.

Comment: Just to be clear the Global Secondary Index is formed of only HashKey and no range Key, how do i generate a query for it using DynamoDBMapper?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

On your DynamoDB annotated model object, you should use `@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "gsiIndexName)` to signify that it is a hash key for the GSI:

```java
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "myTable")
public class MyTable {
    ...

    @DynamoDBIndexHashKey(globalSecondaryIndexName = "myGsi")
    public String getGsiHk() {
        return gsiHk;
    }

    ...
}
```

And then use the `query` method on the `DynamoDBMapper`:

```java
final MyTable gsiKeyObj = new MyTable();
gsiKeyObj.setGsiHk("myGsiHkValue");
final DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyTable> queryExpression = 
    new DynamoDBQueryExpression<>();
queryExpression.setHashKeyValues(gsiKeyObj);
queryExpression.setIndexName("myGsi");
queryExpression.setConsistentRead(false);   // cannot use consistent read on GSI
final PaginatedQueryList<MyTable> results = 
    mapper.query(MyTable.class, queryExpression);
```

Comment: Hi..what about @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey. It gives me same problem with IndexRangeKey.

Comment: Hi @mkobit: the code you sent is working perfectly but when i add 
queryExpression.withLimit(10);
it gives this error: Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException' exception.

i am using RxAndroid for the network ops

Comment: @Shaw I'm not familiar with Android specifics, but I'm guessing that you can't do blocking calls on the main UI thread - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: I have found the solution. If you want to set limit on the DynamoDBQueryExpression object, then use mapper.queryPage() method, not mapper.query()
Its a weird error on Amazon SDK that if we call mapper.query() method with limit parameter set, it gives NetworkOnMainThreadException :D :D

Comment: hello everyone i am able to connect to dynamo db successfully but my result set contains no data...thats strange what else i can look for to resolve .