# How to query a Dynamo DB table without knowing the table name before runtime?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to query a Dynamo DB table based on an attribute `UpdateTime` such that I get the records which are updated in the last 24 hours. But this attribute is not an index in the table. I understand that I need to make this column as an index. But I do not know how do I write a query expression for this.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457820/how-to-query-a-dynamo-db-having-a-gsi-with-only-hashkeys-using-dynamodbmapper) question but the problem is I do not know the table name on which I want to query before runtime.

Answer (score 1):

To find out the table names in your DynamoDB instance, you can use the "ListTables" API:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ListTables.html.

Another way to view tables and their data is via the DynamoDB Console: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ConsoleDynamoDB.html.

Once you know the table name, you can either create an index with the `UpdateTime` attribute as a key or scan the whole table to get the results you want.  Keep in mind that scanning a table is a costly operation.

Alternatively you can create a DynamoDB Stream that captures all of the changes to your tables:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html.

Comment: I made `UpdateTime` as an index and have decided to use `QuerySpec` to query the table, something like:  `QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec().withHashKey........` I do not know how to write the query spec for this case where I need all records updated in last 24 hours. Can you help me in this?