# How I can get items from DynamoDBIndexHashKey?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to specify. May I receive elements only from `DynamoDBIndexHashKey`, not use `DynamoDBHashKey`?

I have a table with fields

```
@DynamoDBIndexHashKey (attributeName = "count", globalSecondaryIndexName = "count-index")
@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="cluster_output_Id)"
@DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName="last_fetch)"
```

I have no @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey

It's code:

```
 MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
    myEntity.setCount(1);    // Integer
    DynamoDBQueryExpression<NewsDynamoDb> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<NewsDynamoDb>()
            .withHashKeyValues(myEntity)
            .withIndexName("count-index");
    queryExpression.setConsistentRead(false);
    List<MyEntity> myCollection = mapper.query(MyEntity.class, queryExpression);
```

Error:

```
AmazonServiceException: Status Code: 400, AWS Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2, AWS Request ID: I97S04LDGO6FSF56OCJ8S3K167VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG, AWS Error Code: ValidationException, AWS Error Message: One or more parameter values were invalid: Invalid number of argument(s) for the EQ ComparisonOperator
```

How I can get items from `DynamoDBIndexHashKey`?

P.s. Scan - work but not interesting to me, because in a further I want a sorting
Query with DynamoDBHashKey work. I have problems with DynamoDBIndexHashKey

[same example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457820/how-to-query-a-dynamo-db-having-a-gsi-with-only-hashkeys-using-dynamodbmapper)

Answer (score 2):

It is the answer to my question

entity:

```
 @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="cluster_output_Id")
public Integer getCluster_output_Id() {
    return cluster_output_Id;
}

@DynamoDBIndexHashKey(attributeName = "count", globalSecondaryIndexName = "count-index")
public Integer getCount() {
    return count;
}

@DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName="last_fetch")
@DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(attributeName = "last_fetch", globalSecondaryIndexName = "count-index")
public Date getLast_fetch() {
    return last_fetch;
}
```

code:

```
dynamoDBMapper = new DynamoDBMapper(amazonDynamoDBClient);
MyClass myClass= new MyClass();
DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyClass > queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<MyClass >();
        myClass.setCount(1);
queryExpression.setHashKeyValues(myClass);
queryExpression.withIndexName("count-index");  // it's not necessarily
Condition rangeKeyCondition = new Condition();
rangeKeyCondition.withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.NE)
        .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(""));
queryExpression.setConsistentRead(false);  
List entities = dynamoDBMapper.query(MyClass.class, queryExpression);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

like explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSIJavaDocumentAPI.Example.html)

```
 Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("tableName");
 Index index = table.getIndex("count-index");
 ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = null;
 QuerySpec querySpec = new QuerySpec();

querySpec.withKeyConditionExpression("count= :v_count > 0 ")
                .withValueMap(new ValueMap()                  .withString(":v_count","1");
 items = index.query(querySpec);

 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   //.......
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I use QuerySpec  I have an error  `Exception in thread "rresqTaskExecutor-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.RequestClientOptions.appendUserAgent (Ljava/lang/String;)`  maybe you know why? I change dependencies

Comment: @AlexanderVysotski I guess you may be missing AWSJavaSDK, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/RequestClientOptions.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Query to find items based on sort/range key only.

You can read more [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#QueryAndScan.Query).

> In a Query operation, you use the KeyConditionExpression parameter to determine the items to be read from the table or index. **You must specify the partition key name and value as an equality condition**. You can optionally provide a second condition for the sort key (if present).

In this case your options are:

1. Scan operation with last_fetch as filter.
2. Redesign your database to have a GSI with last_fetch as partition key

Comment: Can I use DynamoDBIndexHashKey + DynamoDBRangeKey на last_fetch? And can you write an example.. Because if I write DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName="last_fetch) and DynamoDBIndexRangeKey(attributeName = "last_fetch", localSecondaryIndexName = "count-index")  - I have an error the last_fetch not consist in "count-index"

Comment: You haven't specified the index name in DynamoDBRangeKey. Try this - DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName="last_fetch", globalSecondaryIndexName="last_fetch_index"). Don't forget to create last_fetch_index GSI first

Comment: sorry `DynamoDBRangeKey`  and `DynamoDBIndexRangeKey (localSecondaryIndexName = "count-index")`  together on`last_fetch` . - I have an error the last_fetch not consist in "count-index"

Comment: Could you post the code changes you have made? What is the complete error? When do you get the error?

Comment: It is not actual any more, I have found the solution of this problem. The problem was in dependencies which I used with S3 earlier. and also http.client .  (It is my mistake)
Now I use DynamoDB in full. Thank you.